# mgt-login set userDetails not work for email and image

Tags: microsoft-graph-toolkit

I am following the doc 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/components/login
and testing mg-login control and I find when I set the userDetails property of it, it will not show email or image (I set an image url in it).
Is it a bug or I missed something?

Below is my test code.

```html
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@microsoft/mgt/dist/bundle/mgt-loader.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <mgt-login id="lgc"></mgt-login>
    <mgt-teams-channel-picker></mgt-teams-channel-picker>
    <script>
        let loginControl = document.getElementById('lgc');
        loginControl.userDetails = {
            displayName: 'Justin Liu',
            email: 'justin@contoso.com',
            profileImage: 'https://www.baidu.com/img/pc_2e4ef5c71eaa9e3a3ed7fa3a388ec733.png'
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

[issue image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGn4X.png)

Comment: Have you considered using mgt-person control with customized userDetails instead of mgt-login component?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Pan. I am on the study purpose so I will not change it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this to our attention. You're correct this seems to be a bug, I've filled an issue here:

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-toolkit/issues/401

Comment: It appears that you can use:
`personImage: 'https://www.baidu.com/img/pc_2e4ef5c71eaa9e3a3ed7fa3a388ec733.png'`

Instead of profileImage

Comment: Yes, personImage is ok, but still the email cannot be displayed.

Comment: Thanks again for following up, we're updating the documentation, the correct format should be:

        `loginControl.userDetails = {
            displayName: 'Justin Liu',
            mail: 'justin@contoso.com',
            personImage: 'https://www.baidu.com/img/pc_2e4ef5c71eaa9e3a3ed7fa3a388ec733.png'
        }`

Where `mail` instead of `email` will be correct.